# How to export only a single layer as image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

The title isn't precise - I know I can just make only this one layer visible and then save as e.g. `PNG`. But my question is - do I **have to** make all other layers invisible in order to save only my 1 single layer as image? Or is there a way to save only a single layer (or a few at once) without hiding the rest of them?

**Edit:**
Let me rephrase my question - can Photoshop export to an image from only one layer (and not all visible ones)?

Comment: It may be easier to just copy it and paste as a new image (but I'm not a Photoshop user, so I can't tell for sure how it will work)

Comment: No, hiding the other layers is easy enough but I want to know if it's necessary.

Comment: If your concern is remembering which layers to restore: 1) Alt+click (on Windows) the layer you want to export. 2) File, Save as. Select "as a copy" and save your file. If PSD, also uncheck "layers". 3) Undo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've managed to learn - it's impossible to avoid hiding layers. Photoshop always uses all visible layers to create an image.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `File > Scripts > Export Layers to Files`. You will have to delete the non desired layer images afterwards though. This could also be accomplished better with a custom script, but that gets more complex.

Update:

You could also `right-click` the layer in the layer palette and select `Duplicate Layer`. Choose `New` in the document dropdown to paste the layer into it's own empty file. You can then save or export that. This functionality could also be accomplished in a script.

Comment: This script duplicates the document being exported but the exporting itself still uses all layers, I believe. I actually **am** writing a custom script but I still have to use all layers. AFAIK, at least.

Comment: @NPS Updated answer